# Setup ASR protection on a virtual machine with a Hyper-V host running Windows 10

Tags: azure, hyper-v

I am trying to migrate an on-premise virtual machine from a Windows 10 Hyper-V host to Azure using ASR.

My question is that - Is it possible to run the Azure Site Recovery Provider on a client computer that is running Windows 10? I am trying to install AzureSiteRecoveryProvider.exe however I'm getting the following error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a supported configuration. ASR is only supported on Hyper-V hosts running Server 2016 or Server 2012 R2

[image]

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/hyper-v-azure-support-matrix